# Is there any correspondence between Jacobi forms and automorphic forms on the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, mirror-symmetry, information-geometry

Apologies in advance if this question is obvious (or obviously false); number theory is far from my area of expertise. Let me state my questions and then I'll explain the motivation for asking them.

1. Is there any correspondence between automorphic forms on the Siegel-Jacobi space [A] and those on the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$?
2. If so, is there a way to understand this correspondence in terms of lifts from modular forms on hyperbolic space to these two spaces?
3. More generally, is there relationship between the spectral data of a ball in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and higher Siegel-Jacobi spaces?

This might seem like a random question, so let me explain the motivation. Recently, a collaborator and I found a duality between the Seigel-Jacobi space and the Siegel domain $$\Omega = \{ (z_1,z_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 ~|~ Re(z_1) - Re(z_2)^2 > 0 \},$$ which is biholomorphic to a ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$. (See Section 2 and Subsection 2.6 of [this preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.13809).) This construction is closely related to T-duality from mirror symmetry, although the spaces at hand are not Calabi-Yau manifolds. Furthermore, both of these spaces are built as models of the tangent bundle for hyperbolic space $T \mathbb{H}$ (when $\mathbb{H}$ is understood as the moduli space of univariate Gaussian distributions).

A literature search returned up something known as the Saito-Kurokawa lift, which takes modular forms to Siegel modular forms of a higher degree. However, it seems that this lift can be constructed from an intermediate lift from modular forms (i.e., a modular form on $\mathbb{H}$) to a Jacobi from (which I believe is an automorphic form on the Siegel-Jacobi space?). As such, one natural question is whether there is a dual lift from modular forms to certain automorphic forms on the Siegel domain.

By analogy, mirror symmetry for Calabi-Yau manifolds induces correspondences between the enumerative geometry on each space. The hope would be that since all the spaces which appear here also show up in number theory, it might also induce some correspondences in terms of the spectral data of these three spaces.

[A] *Yang, Jae-Hyun*, [**Geometry and arithmetic on the Siegel-Jacobi space**](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-11523-8_10), Ochiai, Takushiro (ed.) et al., Geometry and analysis on manifolds. In memory of Professor Shoshichi Kobayashi. Cham: Birkhäuser/Springer (ISBN 978-3-319-11522-1/hbk; 978-3-319-11523-8/ebook). Progress in Mathematics 308, 275-325 (2015). [ZBL1317.32042](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1317.32042).